# Which open-source cryptocurrency exchange software is best?

Tags: blockchain, exchanges, open-source

like BlinkTrade, WLOX, MarginCall, Peatio etc.? However, it should include both bitcoin and ethereum, and if possible a mobile app..

Comment: All those open source crypto exchange projects seem to be dead, or at least not supported to a proper extent.

Comment: i know but i am not able to any other option because creating it from scratch will take lot of time. So, suggest me something or any new project

Comment: * not able able to see any...